# Bootstrap not working with Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

Good evening. I just started with the Angular 2 course offered on udemy and everything was going great, until I had to install bootstrap on it.

I went step by step with the installation but for some reason when I try to add any bootstrap tags, the whole page becomes white. Here is my code:

-- app.component.ts

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { StocksComponent } from './stocks.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Hello Angular2!';
  today = new Date();
}
```

-- app.component.html

```
<ngb-alert>
  Testing...
</ngb-alert>


{{today | date: "dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm a"}}

<h1 style="color:white" myHighlight>
  {{title}}
</h1>

<a routerLink="/stocks">STOCKS</a>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

-- app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MutualfundsComponent } from './mutualfunds/mutualfunds.component';
import { StocksComponent } from './stocks.component';
import { StockDirectiveDirective } from './stock-directive.directive';
import {HighLightDirective} from './highlight.directive';
import {StockService} from './stock.service';
import { DateFormatterPipe } from './date-formatter.pipe';
import {routing} from './app.routing';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import {CurrencyService} from './currency.service';
import { BondsDirective } from './bonds.directive';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MutualfundsComponent,
    StocksComponent,
    StockDirectiveDirective,
    HighLightDirective,
    DateFormatterPipe,
    DashboardComponent,
    BondsDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing,
    NgbModule

  ],
  providers: [StockService, CurrencyService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

-- angular-cli.json

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.26",
    "name": "angular2"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
          "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
          "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
          "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ],

      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "inline": {
      "style": false,
      "template": false
    },
    "spec": {
      "class": false,
      "component": true,
      "directive": true,
      "module": false,
      "pipe": true,
      "service": true
    }
  }
}
```

I hope somebody can help me out with this little problem

Comment: I typed ngb-alert to test if it works on the page, but sadly it just became all white. When I remove that from the app.component.html the page works perfectly right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import the `NgbModule` as a top level module, then you can use in entire module. your import should look like this:

```
imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   FormsModule,
   HttpModule,
   routing,
   NgbModule.forRoot()
]
```

Notice the `.forRoot()` at the import. This should solve the problem.

And you don't need to include the bootstrap bundles on the scripts section of your angular-cli.json.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you so much! I can finally get going haha

Comment: I have the same code (same course!) but a slightly different issue. The bootstrap styling is just not at all applied - did you have this? IF so, how can i solve it?

Comment: @kpollock you mean that CSS isn't styling at all? Are you sure that you're using the right classes and the bootstrap css file that you're importing are the complete version?

Comment: I had an error in the path for the bootstrap.css file! Thanks anyway!